# sort using struct and pointers

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, struct

I am new to structs and pointer. Trying to learn them.Tried a simple sorting function with struct and pointer and but having some issues. Can some one help me understand them?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int*
    sorting (int* arg)
    {

    int temp=0,j,i;
        for(i=1;i<5;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<5-i;j++)
            {
                if(arg[j] >arg[j+1])
                {
                    temp=arg[j];
                    arg[j]=arg[j+1];
                    arg[j+1]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
    return arg;
    }

int main(){

    int i;
    int n =5;
    int *result_;

    int *sorting_1_arg = malloc(n * sizeof *sorting_1_arg);

    printf("Sort\n "); 
    printf("Enter 5 elements to sort: ");       

    for (i =0; i <n; i++){
    scanf("%d", &sorting_1_arg[i]);
    }

    result_4 = sorting(sorting_1_arg);
    printf ("Sorted List recieved from Server ");

    for (i =0; i <n; i++){
    printf("%d",sorting_1_arg[i]);
    }
  return 0;
   }
```

When I run this code:

```
In function 'int main()':
[Error] invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: typo? `int *result_;` --> `int *result_4;`

Comment: That error seems odd from a C compiler, but would make sense if you were compiling this (C) code as C++.

Comment: Fixing the typo @BLUEPIXY noted, and compiling as C, all seems fine: https://ideone.com/yBWcKt

Comment: Some compilers give error if explicit cast is not made for the void pointer returned by Malloc, you an explicitly cast return value from Malloc, sorting_1_org=(int *) malloc

Comment: @PaulRoub I was voteup your comments (long before).

Comment: @RADAR those compilers are either broken, or are C++ compilers.

Answer (score 0):

The programs seems fine to me. Except that there is an undeclared variable on 
line 39:

```
result_4 = sorting(sorting_1_arg);
```

Correct it to

```
result_ = sorting(sorting_1_arg);
```

The program runs fine. Just add a "\n" for new lines to make it look better.

The site in [here](http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-structures) gives you a good introduction to structures and pointers.